# JSON Loop using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, loops

After reading some questions here, I still have difficulty on making a loop through my JSON results.
Here they are:

```
{
    "data": {
        "posts": [
            {
            "Post": {
                "id": "1",
                "user_id": "1",
                "title": "Test Content",
                "created": "2011-06-30"
                }
            },
            {
                "Post": {
                "id": "2",
                "user_id": "2",
                "title": "New Test Content",
                "created": "2011-06-30"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I get Post.title using $.each() ?

Comment: It would help a lot if you indented correctly.

Comment: Indentation accomplished

Comment: @SimpleCoder - almost ;)

Comment: Ah, jsFiddle has let me down...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$.each(jsonObject.data.posts, function(index, val){
    alert(val.Post.title); //Do what you want to the title
});
```

Comment: HI! thnks for the reply. Doing what you suggest is giving me a "a is undefined" on debug... is it becouse it comes empty?

Comment: @pedrosss What is the object that holds the json data?

Comment: I was doing a $.getJSON('url-here', function(data) and retreiving the result as showed in the question...

Comment: ignore the comment before, i was using "data" as the jsonObject.. :P Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVAt2/).

Example target to output values:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

jQuery Call to Object, iterate over "posts".

```
/* Create an Object from your JSON data, added based on comment about return results via URL */
var dataObj = JSON.parse(<put your JSON data here>);

$.each(dataObj.data.posts, function(idx, val) {
    /* Show ID */
    $('#output').append($('<p></p>').html('ID = ' + val.Post.id));   

    /* Show Title */
    $('#output').append($('<p></p>').html('Title = ' + val.Post.title));   
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it returns error since i dont know what to put in "dataObj", (im getting the json trough a url)

Comment: Your result should be a JSON data, you should use the JSON.parse() function to parse the data into an object.  You can get the official JavaScript JSON library at [JSON.org](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).